# Can't activate Windows Sandbox in Windows 11 virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-sandbox, nested-virtualization

I'm trying to use VM to run a game and apparently I need to enable the GPU in the VM, and to do that I need to use Windows Sandbox (WSB) in the VM, but I can't get WSB enabled, the checkbox is grayed out, and when I put the cursor on it, this message appears:

"**Windows Sandbox cannot be installed: The processor does not have the required virtualization capabilities**."

- I have a home edition of Windows 10, which runs an Enterprise edition of Windows 11 in Virtual Box.
- My processor is an intel
- Hyper-V is enabled on W11
- I ran the "**\VBoxManage modifyvm VMNAME --nested-hw-virt on**" command on my real machine, which does not show any errors
- In VirtualBox, the **VT-x** option in the System->Processor menu is checked

If someone has an idea, I'm interested, thanks.

Comment: WSB is a virtual machine. And no, you can't run a windows virtual machine hypervisor inside a virtual machine.

Comment: So WSB is only activable on a real machine ?

Comment: “you can't run a windows virtual machine hypervisor inside a virtual machine.” - This is absolutely false

Comment: I await correction, but my understanding is that none of the nested virtualization APIs are interoperable.

Comment: `That means that you can install a hypervisor, such as Oracle VM VirtualBox, Oracle VM Server or KVM, on an Oracle VM VirtualBox guest.` [From the VirtualBox User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#nested-virt), and that *might be hinting* that it does not have the capability of getting the Microsoft hypervisor to run inside its VMs.

Comment: You may give [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#hyperv-support) a shot btw. I mean to enable the hypervisor platform or whatsoever ("castrated Hyper-V" on Home *officially* gifted by Microsoft for WSL?) on your Home host and make VirtualBox use the Microsoft hypervisor as its engine. While I suggested it, there's only glimpse chance that it could help at all. Btw, are you even sure that `to enable the GPU in the VM I need to use Windows Sandbox (WSB) in the VM` is true? They don't sound related to me at all.

Comment: What are you referring to exactly by `enable the GPU in the VM` anyway? AFAIK it's not even a thing in the case of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Sandbox requires a Type 1 hypervisor, meaning Hyper-V.
In addition, to run Sandbox on a virtual machine,
nested virtualization must be enabled.

Nested virtualization allows running Hyper-V on a virtual machine.
In addition, it allows Windows Sandbox to run on a virtual machine,
as it is itself a light-weight virtual machine.

Running Sandbox in a virtual machine has the additional bonus of being
able to save the sandbox by taking snapshots of the VM while the
sandbox is open.

While not being able to guarantee success for your setup,
a PowerShell script was posted to enable nested virtualization on a VM -
[Nested.ps1](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AExY06pYsU8BprE&id=FCDCA7D2E5A3FC02%21214572&cid=FCDCA7D2E5A3FC02&parId=root&parQt=sharedby&parCid=A53CA3C46843F896&o=OneUp).

You will find a video describing how to run the script in the article
[Windows Sandbox on Hyper-V virtual machine](https://win10.guru/windows-sandbox-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine/).

Comment: Thank you, I tried, but even without errors, it doesn't change anything :/ I think it's impossible with a Windows Home licence :/ Maybe if I upgrade my licence ?

Comment: Windows Home was always more restrictive as regarding Hyper-V, so it's possible that an upgrade would help. But, again, there is no guarantee for success. The Enterprise version has the most features. Before spending money, check out first [this article](https://petri.com/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-hyper-v/).

Comment: It's worked with Hyper-V only, thank you :)

Comment: the answer was the comment, we can't activate Windows Sandbox in a vitual machine without Hyper-V. I can't check the comment, sadly :/

Comment: The "Type 1 hypervisor" in my answer was of course Hyper-V. I clarified my answer.